# Python+Celery: Chaining jobs?

Tags: python, celery

The [Celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) suggests that it's a bad idea to have tasks wait on the results of other tasks… But the suggested solution (see “good” heading) leaves a something to be desired. Specifically, there's no clear way of getting the subtask's result back to the caller (also, it's kind of ugly).

So, is there any way of “chaining” jobs, so the caller gets the result of the final job? Eg, to use the `add` example:

```
>>> add3 = add.subtask(args=(3, ))
>>> add.delay(1, 2, callback=add3).get()
6
```

Alternately, is it OK to return instances of Result? For example:

```
@task
def add(x, y, callback=None):
    result = x + y
    if callback:
        return subtask(callback).delay(result)
    return result
```

This would let the result of the “final” job in the chain could be retrived with a simple:

```
result = add(1, 2, callback=add3).delay()
while isinstance(result, Result):
    result = result.get()
print "result:", result
```

Comment: What you propose would work fine. I don't see any alternative, do you?

Comment: unfortunately the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) do not explain why chaining is better.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do it with a celery chain. See https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains

```
@task()
def add(a, b):
    time.sleep(5) # simulate long time processing
    return a + b
```

Chaining job:

```
# import chain from celery import chain
# the result of the first add job will be 
# the first argument of the second add job
ret = chain(add.s(1, 2), add.s(3)).apply_async()

# another way to express a chain using pipes
ret2 = (add.s(1, 2) | add.s(3)).apply_async()

...

# check ret status to get result
if ret.status == u'SUCCESS':
    print "result:", ret.get()
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get result of a chained process like this suggestion but get warning :

`[2016-09-15 16:20:52,684: WARNING/Worker-7] /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py:45: RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!
`See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks``

`In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
raised instead of just being a warning.`

I am using subtasks chained as `result = chain(...,...,...).delay().get()` can you explain why it raise a problem despite subtasks are handled by chain method?

Comment: Using the .get() method makes a blocking call, which can lead to deadlock.

Comment: The `celery` docs say it is bad to call multiple tasks with `.delay().get()` and they offer an [alternative](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) but they do not explain **why** the alternative is better. why is the alternative technique of chaining better? does the chaining method just use a timeout and so avoids possible deadlike (i.e. `.delay().get(timeout=1.0)` )?