# Get progress from async python celery chain by chain id

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to get the progress of a task chain by querying each task status.
But when retrieving the chain by it's id, I get some object that behaves differently.

**In tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks')
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

def unpack_chain(nodes): 
    while nodes.parent:
        yield nodes.parent
        nodes = nodes.parent
    yield nodes

@celery.task
def add(num, num2):
    return num + num2
```

**When quering from ipython...**

```
In [43]: from celery import chain
In [44]: from tasks import celery, add, unpack_chain
In [45]: c = chain(add.s(3,3), add.s(10).set(countdown=100))
In [46]: m = c.apply_async()
In [47]: a = celery.AsyncResult(m.id)
In [48]: a == m
Out[48]: True
In [49]: a.id == m.id
Out[49]: True
In [50]: [t.status for t in list(unpack_chain(a))]
Out[50]: ['PENDING']
In [51]: [t.status for t in list(unpack_chain(m))]
Out[51]: ['PENDING', 'SUCCESS']
```

Using Python 2.7.3 and Celery 3.0.19 under Redis.

As you can see in **50 & 51**, the value returned by `celery.AsyncResult` differs from the original chain.

How can I get the original chain tasks list by the chain id?

Comment: seems that celery.AsyncResult looses the result.parent pointers.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if you got anywhere with this -- I'm trying to do a similar thing.

Comment: Asked on irc and even opened a ticket on github but got no help at all. Basically is still broken. Luckly for me, my requirements allowed me to ask for the global status of the chain for some tasks that I grouped in a chain. The other tasks are "appended" to the chain by a pesimistic delay: `mytask.s().set(countdown=980).apply_async()` :(. Please let me know if you got somewhere further.

Comment: I have a set of tasks in a group that I want to be able to post-process results, so I made that part of a chain. However, to get status, it seems the best way is to just deal with a group and then use the GroupResults object to iterate through the individual task results, but then I can't use a chain anymore (which is where I was hitting the problem you were hitting). I'll let you know if I find a way around.

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901101/pythoncelery-chaining-jobs rrr, the problem would be what would you take as the chain id in there....

Answer (score 12):

Like @Hernantz said, you can't recover the parent chain from just the task ID, you'd have to iterate over your queue which may or may not be possible depending on what you use as a broker.

But if you have the last task id to do the lookup then you have the chain, you just need to store all the task ids and rebuild the chain when you need to examine their status. You can use the following functions:

```
def store(node):
    id_chain = []
    while node.parent:
      id_chain.append(node.id)
      node = node.parent
    id_chain.append(node.id)
    return id_chain

def restore(id_chain):
    id_chain.reverse()
    last_result = None
    for tid in id_chain:
        result = celery.AsyncResult(tid)
        result.parent = last_result
        last_result = result
    return last_result
```

Call store when you first get a AsyncResult from chain. Calling restore on that will give you a linked list of `AsyncResult`s like chain gives you.