# Celery AsyncResult does not have parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I submit 3 tasks which are chained together. Then I return the id of the chain with which later on I am trying to access the results

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from my_celery impor app

def get_results(task_id):
    result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=app)
    if result.ready():
        return result.get()
    return result.state
```

This AsyncResult is the result of the last task in chain. It also does not have its chain parents.

Is this a bug or I am doing somethign wrong?

Comment: Have you checked `children` property of result?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. It seems parent and children properties do not contain other tasks in a chain, but instead only tasks that are submitted from that task. Problem I am facing is that just knowing the id of the last task in a chain, it is not possible to determine the state of the chain (whether it is still PENDING or actually FAILED).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer here (it's likely an outdated method) - [Get progress from async python celery chain by chain id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306175/get-progress-from-async-python-celery-chain-by-chain-id), it mentions the following:

> you can't recover the parent chain from just the task ID, you'd have to iterate over your queue which may or may not be possible depending on what you use as a broker.

In that case, you'd have to follow the method as suggested in that answer. But from also what I can see in the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.app) for `AsyncResult()`, you should be able to pass the parent parameter as an argument and it should hold the parent value for a child. It's by default passed as `None`, as can be seen from the method signature.

```
class celery.result.AsyncResult(id, backend=None, task_name=None, app=None, parent=None)
```

Comment: It is actually a really weird that it is not possible to track chain status when every task in a chain depends on the previous ones. It is required to manually inspect each task  and validate its state.

Comment: I see. I am not entirely familiar with Celery so that was all I could find. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I already had a workaround that saves all task ids instead of one and the state is decided based on all task states. This works alright while as long as chains are relatively simple. Still, going to dig a bit more into it, because it seems for me that this functionality is quite convenient tho perhaps I do not see the whole picture as I am still a celery rookie.