# Use Celery for a pipeline

Tags: python, celery

Is this the best way to use Celery for a pipeline: TaskA -> TaskB -> TaskC? I know nothing about Celery and the documentation really don't explain too much how things should be done in real application.

```
@app.task
def taskA(t_id):
    if success:
        TaskB.delay(t_id)
    else:
        ReportError.delay(t_id)

@app.task
def taskAA(t_id):
    if success:
        TaskB.delay(t_id)
    else:
        ReportError.delay(t_id)

@app.task
def taskB(t_id):
    if success:
        TaskC.delay(t_id)
    else:
        ReportError.delay(t_id)
```

Maybe I shouldn't use Celery for this kind of Task...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901101/pythoncelery-chaining-jobs

Comment: Use celery chain https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains has described in the linked answer in the previous comment.

Comment: @MauroRocco One thing I don't like Chain is that it is sequential without any branching. For example, for taskA I may need to start a image downloader and a video downloader, and after video downloader I will need a segmenter. Maybe celery is not the right framework for this kind of task? I am looking for a way to statically construct the flow of the system, and I can feed t_id to taskA and everything will just work.

Comment: @YifanZhang I think you should really read with attention this page http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html . Celery allow you to construct different workflow type, you could for example use group and chord together to make some parallel work and than call a final task that aggregates.

Answer (score 6):

As the other commenters state, you can use a chain. See https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains for more info. Based on your original question, like so:

```
from celery import chain

ret = chain(taskA.s(), taskB.s(), taskC.s()).apply_async()

if ret.status == u'SUCCESS':
    print "result:", ret.get()
```