# Does celery allow tasks execute one by one?

Tags: python, celery

```
@celery.tasks
def a():
   time.sleep(2)
   print 'aaa'

@celery.tasks
def b():
   time.sleep(2)
   print 'bbb'
```

Now I want when celery take task-a and task-b at the same time, task-a execute  first, and then the task-b should execute after task-a. DOes celery allow this happend?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12034239/89435

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running "unique" tasks with celery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095940/running-unique-tasks-with-celery)

Comment: @mavroprovato thanks a lot. I use `chain` like this: `@celery_app.task
def c():
 ret = chain(a.s(), b.s()).apply_async()
 print 'ccccc'`  but there is error:`raised unexpected: TypeError('b() takes no arguments (1 given)',)`. If task a and b does not have arguments, how to handle this situation?

Comment: @ChillarAnand thanks very much. Now I have another question, maybe it have some relation to your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352863/i-use-celery-to-simultaneously-execute-my-tasks-but-it-maybe-happened-race-cond