# How to execute celery task after another already executing task in python?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I need to execute secobd celery task after the first one is ready. The first task is already running and I have its id. How can I link another one to it?

```
# first task
first_task = change_timezone_geodata_task.delay(node.id, timezone, geodata_id)
task_id=  first_task .id
new task = change_timezone_geodata_task.delay(node2.id, timezone2, geodata_id2)
```

How to make new task execute after task ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python+Celery: Chaining jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901101/pythoncelery-chaining-jobs)

Comment: No, I do not start them at the same time, the first task is already started by just 'delay' andI have its task_id

Comment: `Tasks can be linked together: the linked task is called when the task returns successfully:`

The first line from the docs. You don't start them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind as solution to your problem is to rely on Celery's [task linking](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks) capability.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your task is running right now so by having id you can find out if your task is done or not it was from this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753040/retrieve-task-result-by-id-in-celery)

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from .tasks import app

res = AsyncResult('655890aa-4f02-467d-aaca-20004b70efe8d',app=app)
status = res.state # 'SUCCESS'

from .tasks import task2
if status == 'SUCCESS':
    task2.delay()
```

But if you want to run them after each other at the first you can use this:

> If you don't want your callback to accept the result of the previous
> task as an argument, you can make your linked partial immutable by
> using si() instead of s()
>
> (as mentioned in [there](https://getdjangosaas.com/celery-task-callback/#:%7E:text=focus%20on%20callbacks.-,Callbacks,argument%20of%20the%20callback%20task.))
>
> ```
> from tasks import sum, increase_counter
> ​
> sum.apply_async((8,8), link=increase_counter.si()) # Calculate 8 + 8 and increase counter of sum task calls
> ```